# PowerShell Remote not working via Harness for non-Administrator user

Tags: winrm

I am trying to connect to a Windows Server 2016 server using WinRM via Harness. I have added the user to the "Remote Management Users" group on the server but I receive an "Access Is Denied" when testing the connection to the server. If I add the same user to the "Administrators" group on the server, Harness is able to connect.

I have attempted adding the user to the PowerShell Endpoint Security Configuration but this didn't have any effect.

The account is part of a domain and Harness is authenticating using NTLM.

Answer (score 0):

On the server that you are trying to conenct to, enter `winrm configSDDL default` in a Command Prompt as an Administrator and give the "Remote Management Users" local group Full Access.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is still an issue, but I am with Harness support and had run into this problem recently, and went ahead and wrote a KB on it so hopefully no one goes through that fun again :)

https://community.harness.io/t/configure-the-winrm-service-on-a-windows-host-to-allow-authentication-and-remoting-from-non-administrator-user-accounts/562

Comment: This appears to be the correct url: https://discuss.harness.io/t/configure-the-winrm-service-on-a-windows-host-to-allow-authentication-and-remoting-from-non-administrator-user-accounts/562